# How do I work with denormalization using two different collections?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a mobile travel application.

I have two tables:

Agency table:

- title
- address
- phone

Packs table:

- id
- offer
- agency (map: {businessId (string), title (string) })

Agencies can have many packs, but each pack can only have one agency.

On the main page, I will have the DISCOVER section. In this case, I know that with denormalization, I can display the packs and any desired data from the agency.

My question arises when I enter the pack details page. I want to display all the agency's information and a ListView of all the packs that the agency has. How would I do this, considering that I denormalize in the packs?

I know that I could make a reference in the AGENCY collection, but I think it would be a problem to have many references in a single document. Is that correct?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

In your current model, you can get the packs for an agency by filtering on the `agency` of the `packs` documents. So you'd perform two operations:

1. Read the agency document
2. Use a query to get the packs documents for that agency

But if a pack always belongs to one agency, consider making a packs **sub**collection under each `agency` document:

```
agencies (collection)
  agency1: { title: "", addres: "", phone: "", ...} (document)
    packs (collection)
      pack1: { ... } (doc)
      pack2: { ... } (doc)
  agency2: { title: "", addres: "", phone: "", ...} (document)
    packs (collection)
      pack1: { ... } (doc)
      pack2: { ... } (doc)
```

So now you can get the packs for an agency by reading the entire `packs` subcollection of that agency document. It doesn't change the number of operations required, as you still need separate reads for the agency document and the subcollection, but it *does* lead to better data separation which improves write performance.

Also see:

- The Firestore documentation on its [data model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model), specifically the section on [subcollections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections)

Comment: Is the first time using firebase, but I think that your solution make a lot of sense and for me. Like this I avoid doing functions to update the data. One thing that I forget, users can save as favorites the packs. Is that possible with subcollections? Thanks

Comment: One more question. How this packs will be inside agency. When I load the agency in the discovery listview, this will affect the reads?